# NameError: uninitialized constant Shipment with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to write rspec test cases with rspec-mock. But, I got an error as follow. order_decorator_spec.rb:149 is `let!(:order) { create(:order, shipments: [shipment]) }`. It doesn't show any stacktrace perhaps bacause it is executed on RubyMine console. How can I fix the problem??

console

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Shipment
./spec/models/spree/order_decorator_spec.rb:149:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

order_decorator_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Spree::Order do
  context '#after_cancel' do

    let!(:shipment) { double(:shipment, :cancel! => '')}
    before {shipment}
    let!(:order) { create(:order, shipments: [shipment]) }

    before do
      order.stub(:after_cancel)
    end

    it "should adsfasdfasdfa" do
      shipment.should_receive(:cancel!).once
      order.after_cancel
    end
  end
end
```

order.rb

```
require 'spree/core/validators/email'
require 'spree/order/checkout'

module Spree
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Checkout

    checkout_flow do
      go_to_state :address
      go_to_state :delivery
      go_to_state :payment, if: ->(order) {
        order.update_totals
        order.payment_required?
      }
      go_to_state :confirm, if: ->(order) { order.confirmation_required? }
      go_to_state :complete
      remove_transition from: :delivery, to: :confirm
    end

    token_resource

    attr_reader :coupon_code

    if Spree.user_class
      belongs_to :user, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
      belongs_to :created_by, class_name: Spree.user_class.to_s
    else
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :created_by
    end

    belongs_to :bill_address, foreign_key: :bill_address_id, class_name: 'Spree::Address'
    alias_attribute :billing_address, :bill_address

    belongs_to :ship_address, foreign_key: :ship_address_id, class_name: 'Spree::Address'
    alias_attribute :shipping_address, :ship_address

    has_many :state_changes, as: :stateful
    has_many :line_items, -> { order('created_at ASC') }, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :return_authorizations, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :adjustments, -> { order("#{Adjustment.table_name}.created_at ASC") }, as: :adjustable, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :line_item_adjustments, through: :line_items, source: :adjustments
    has_many :all_adjustments, class_name: 'Spree::Adjustment'
    has_many :inventory_units

    has_many :shipments, dependent: :destroy do
      def states
        pluck(:state).uniq
      end
    end

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ship_address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipments

    # Needs to happen before save_permalink is called
    before_validation :set_currency
    before_validation :generate_order_number, on: :create
    before_validation :clone_billing_address, if: :use_billing?
    attr_accessor :use_billing

    before_create :link_by_email
    after_create :create_tax_charge!

    validates :email, presence: true, if: :require_email
    validates :email, email: true, if: :require_email, allow_blank: true
    validate :has_available_shipment
    validate :has_available_payment

    make_permalink field: :number

    class_attribute :update_hooks
    self.update_hooks = Set.new

    def self.by_number(number)
      where(number: number)
    end

    def self.between(start_date, end_date)
      where(created_at: start_date..end_date)
    end

    def self.by_customer(customer)
      joins(:user).where("#{Spree.user_class.table_name}.email" => customer)
    end

    def self.by_state(state)
      where(state: state)
    end

    def self.complete
      where.not(completed_at: nil)
    end

    def self.incomplete
      where(completed_at: nil)
    end

    # Use this method in other gems that wish to register their own custom logic
    # that should be called after Order#update
    def self.register_update_hook(hook)
      self.update_hooks.add(hook)
    end

    # For compatiblity with Calculator::PriceSack
    def amount
      line_items.inject(0.0) { |sum, li| sum + li.amount }
    end

    def currency
      self[:currency] || Spree::Config[:currency]
    end

    def display_outstanding_balance
      Spree::Money.new(outstanding_balance, { currency: currency })
    end

    def display_item_total
      Spree::Money.new(item_total, { currency: currency })
    end

    def display_adjustment_total
      Spree::Money.new(adjustment_total, { currency: currency })
    end

    def display_tax_total
      Spree::Money.new(tax_total, { currency: currency })
    end

    def display_ship_total
      Spree::Money.new(ship_total, { currency: currency })
    end

    def display_total
      Spree::Money.new(total, { currency: currency })
    end

    def to_param
      number.to_s.to_url.upcase
    end

    def completed?
      completed_at.present? || complete?
    end

    # Indicates whether or not the user is allowed to proceed to checkout.
    # Currently this is implemented as a check for whether or not there is at
    # least one LineItem in the Order.  Feel free to override this logic in your
    # own application if you require additional steps before allowing a checkout.
    def checkout_allowed?
      line_items.count > 0
    end

    # Is this a free order in which case the payment step should be skipped
    def payment_required?
      total.to_f > 0.0
    end

    # If true, causes the confirmation step to happen during the checkout process
    def confirmation_required?
      Spree::Config[:always_include_confirm_step] ||
        payments.valid.map(&:payment_method).compact.any?(&:payment_profiles_supported?) ||
        # Little hacky fix for #4117
        # If this wasn't here, order would transition to address state on confirm failure
        # because there would be no valid payments any more.
        state == 'confirm'
    end

    # Indicates the number of items in the order
    def item_count
      line_items.inject(0) { |sum, li| sum + li.quantity }
    end

    def backordered?
      shipments.any?(&:backordered?)
    end

    # Returns the relevant zone (if any) to be used for taxation purposes.
    # Uses default tax zone unless there is a specific match
    def tax_zone
      Zone.match(tax_address) || Zone.default_tax
    end

    # Indicates whether tax should be backed out of the price calcualtions in
    # cases where prices include tax but the customer is not required to pay
    # taxes in that case.
    def exclude_tax?
      return false unless Spree::Config[:prices_inc_tax]
      return tax_zone != Zone.default_tax
    end

    # Returns the address for taxation based on configuration
    def tax_address
      Spree::Config[:tax_using_ship_address] ? ship_address : bill_address
    end

    # Array of totals grouped by Adjustment#label. Useful for displaying line item
    # adjustments on an invoice. For example, you can display tax breakout for
    # cases where tax is included in price.
    def line_item_adjustment_totals
      Hash[self.line_item_adjustments.eligible.group_by(&:label).map do |label, adjustments|
        total = adjustments.sum(&:amount)
        [label, Spree::Money.new(total, { currency: currency })]
      end]
    end

    def updater
      @updater ||= OrderUpdater.new(self)
    end

    def update!
      updater.update
    end

    def update_totals
      updater.update_totals
    end

    def clone_billing_address
      if bill_address and self.ship_address.nil?
        self.ship_address = bill_address.clone
      else
        self.ship_address.attributes = bill_address.attributes.except('id', 'updated_at', 'created_at')
      end
      true
    end

    def allow_cancel?
      return false unless completed? and state != 'canceled'
      shipment_state.nil? || %w{ready backorder pending}.include?(shipment_state)
    end

    def awaiting_returns?
      return_authorizations.any? { |return_authorization| return_authorization.authorized? }
    end

    def contents
      @contents ||= Spree::OrderContents.new(self)
    end

    # Associates the specified user with the order.
    def associate_user!(user)
      self.user = user
      self.email = user.email
      self.created_by = user if self.created_by.blank?

      if persisted?
        # immediately persist the changes we just made, but don't use save since we might have an invalid address associated
        self.class.unscoped.where(id: id).update_all(email: user.email, user_id: user.id, created_by_id: self.created_by_id)
      end
    end

    # FIXME refactor this method and implement validation using validates_* utilities
    def generate_order_number
      record = true
      while record
        random = "R#{Array.new(9){rand(9)}.join}"
        record = self.class.where(number: random).first
      end
      self.number = random if self.number.blank?
      self.number
    end

    def shipped_shipments
      shipments.shipped
    end

    def contains?(variant)
      find_line_item_by_variant(variant).present?
    end

    def quantity_of(variant)
      line_item = find_line_item_by_variant(variant)
      line_item ? line_item.quantity : 0
    end

    def find_line_item_by_variant(variant)
      line_items.detect { |line_item| line_item.variant_id == variant.id }
    end

    def ship_total
      adjustments.shipping.sum(:amount)
    end

    # Creates new tax charges if there are any applicable rates. If prices already
    # include taxes then price adjustments are created instead.
    def create_tax_charge!
      Spree::TaxRate.adjust(self)
    end

    def outstanding_balance
      total - payment_total
    end

    def outstanding_balance?
     self.outstanding_balance != 0
    end

    def name
      if (address = bill_address || ship_address)
        "#{address.firstname} #{address.lastname}"
      end
    end

    def can_ship?
      self.complete? || self.resumed? || self.awaiting_return? || self.returned?
    end

    def credit_cards
      credit_card_ids = payments.from_credit_card.pluck(:source_id).uniq
      CreditCard.where(id: credit_card_ids)
    end

    # Finalizes an in progress order after checkout is complete.
    # Called after transition to complete state when payments will have been processed
    def finalize!
      touch :completed_at

      # lock all adjustments (coupon promotions, etc.)
      adjustments.update_all state: 'closed'

      # update payment and shipment(s) states, and save
      updater.update_payment_state
      shipments.each do |shipment|
        shipment.update!(self)
        shipment.finalize!
      end

      updater.update_shipment_state
      save
      updater.run_hooks

      deliver_order_confirmation_email
    end

    def deliver_order_confirmation_email
      begin
        OrderMailer.confirm_email(self.id).deliver
      rescue Exception => e
        logger.error("#{e.class.name}: #{e.message}")
        logger.error(e.backtrace * "\n")
      end
    end

    # Helper methods for checkout steps
    def paid?
      payment_state == 'paid' || payment_state == 'credit_owed'
    end

    def available_payment_methods
      @available_payment_methods ||= (PaymentMethod.available(:front_end) + PaymentMethod.available(:both)).uniq
    end

    def pending_payments
      payments.select(&:checkout?)
    end

    # processes any pending payments and must return a boolean as it's
    # return value is used by the checkout state_machine to determine
    # success or failure of the 'complete' event for the order
    #
    # Returns:
    # - true if all pending_payments processed successfully
    # - true if a payment failed, ie. raised a GatewayError
    #   which gets rescued and converted to TRUE when
    #   :allow_checkout_gateway_error is set to true
    # - false if a payment failed, ie. raised a GatewayError
    #   which gets rescued and converted to FALSE when
    #   :allow_checkout_on_gateway_error is set to false
    #
    def process_payments!
      if pending_payments.empty?
        raise Core::GatewayError.new Spree.t(:no_pending_payments)
      else
        pending_payments.each do |payment|
          break if payment_total >= total

          payment.process!

          if payment.completed?
            self.payment_total += payment.amount
          end
        end
      end
    rescue Core::GatewayError => e
      result = !!Spree::Config[:allow_checkout_on_gateway_error]
      errors.add(:base, e.message) and return result
    end

    def billing_firstname
      bill_address.try(:firstname)
    end

    def billing_lastname
      bill_address.try(:lastname)
    end

    def products
      line_items.map(&:product)
    end

    def variants
      line_items.map(&:variant)
    end

    def insufficient_stock_lines
      line_items.select &:insufficient_stock?
    end

    def merge!(order, user = nil)
      order.line_items.each do |line_item|
        next unless line_item.currency == currency
        current_line_item = self.line_items.find_by(variant: line_item.variant)
        if current_line_item
          current_line_item.quantity += line_item.quantity
          current_line_item.save
        else
          line_item.order_id = self.id
          line_item.save
        end
      end

      self.associate_user!(user) if !self.user && !user.blank?

      # So that the destroy doesn't take out line items which may have been re-assigned
      order.line_items.reload
      order.destroy
    end
(snip)
(snip)
(snip)
(snip)
(snip)
(snip)
(snip)
(snip)
      end
    end
```

shipment_decorator.rb

```
require 'ostruct'

module Spree
  Shipment.class_eval do

      def after_ship
        inventory_units.each &:ship!
        adjustment.finalize!
        #send_shipped_email
        touch :shipped_at
      end

  end
end
```

shipment.rb

```
require 'ostruct'

module Spree
  class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order, class_name: 'Spree::Order', touch: true
    belongs_to :address, class_name: 'Spree::Address'
    belongs_to :stock_location, class_name: 'Spree::StockLocation'

    has_many :shipping_rates, dependent: :delete_all
    has_many :shipping_methods, through: :shipping_rates
    has_many :state_changes, as: :stateful
    has_many :inventory_units, dependent: :delete_all
    has_one :adjustment, as: :source, dependent: :destroy

    after_save :ensure_correct_adjustment, :update_order

    attr_accessor :special_instructions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :inventory_units

    make_permalink field: :number, length: 11, prefix: 'H'

    scope :shipped, -> { with_state('shipped') }
    scope :ready,   -> { with_state('ready') }
    scope :pending, -> { with_state('pending') }
    scope :with_state, ->(*s) { where(state: s) }
    scope :trackable, -> { where("tracking IS NOT NULL AND tracking != ''") }

    # shipment state machine (see http://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/tree/master for details)
    state_machine initial: :pending, use_transactions: false do
      event :ready do
        transition from: :pending, to: :ready, if: lambda { |shipment|
          # Fix for #2040
          shipment.determine_state(shipment.order) == 'ready'
        }
      end

      event :pend do
        transition from: :ready, to: :pending
      end

      event :ship do
        transition from: :ready, to: :shipped
      end
      after_transition to: :shipped, do: :after_ship

      event :cancel do
        transition to: :canceled, from: [:pending, :ready]
      end
      after_transition to: :canceled, do: :after_cancel

      event :resume do
        transition from: :canceled, to: :ready, if: lambda { |shipment|
          shipment.determine_state(shipment.order) == :ready
        }
        transition from: :canceled, to: :pending, if: lambda { |shipment|
          shipment.determine_state(shipment.order) == :ready
        }
        transition from: :canceled, to: :pending
      end
      after_transition from: :canceled, to: [:pending, :ready], do: :after_resume
    end

    def to_param
      number
    end

    def backordered?
      inventory_units.any? { |inventory_unit| inventory_unit.backordered? }
    end

    def shipped=(value)
      return unless value == '1' && shipped_at.nil?
      self.shipped_at = Time.now
    end

    def shipping_method
      selected_shipping_rate.try(:shipping_method) || shipping_rates.first.try(:shipping_method)
    end

    def add_shipping_method(shipping_method, selected = false)
      shipping_rates.create(shipping_method: shipping_method, selected: selected)
    end

    def selected_shipping_rate
      shipping_rates.where(selected: true).first
    end

    def selected_shipping_rate_id
      selected_shipping_rate.try(:id)
    end

    def selected_shipping_rate_id=(id)
      shipping_rates.update_all(selected: false)
      shipping_rates.update(id, selected: true)
      self.save!
    end

    def refresh_rates
      return shipping_rates if shipped?
      return [] unless can_get_rates?

      # StockEstimator.new assigment below will replace the current shipping_method
      original_shipping_method_id = shipping_method.try(:id)

      self.shipping_rates = Stock::Estimator.new(order).shipping_rates(to_package)

      if shipping_method
        selected_rate = shipping_rates.detect { |rate|
          rate.shipping_method_id == original_shipping_method_id
        }
        self.selected_shipping_rate_id = selected_rate.id if selected_rate
      end

      shipping_rates
    end

    def currency
      order ? order.currency : Spree::Config[:currency]
    end

    # The adjustment amount associated with this shipment (if any.)  Returns only the first adjustment to match
    # the shipment but there should never really be more than one.
    def cost
      adjustment ? adjustment.amount : 0
    end

    alias_method :amount, :cost

    def display_cost
      Spree::Money.new(cost, { currency: currency })
    end

    alias_method :display_amount, :display_cost

    def item_cost
      line_items.map(&:amount).sum
    end

    def display_item_cost
      Spree::Money.new(item_cost, { currency: currency })
    end

    def total_cost
      cost + item_cost
    end

    def display_total_cost
      Spree::Money.new(total_cost, { currency: currency })
    end

    def editable_by?(user)
      !shipped?
    end

    def manifest
      inventory_units.group_by(&:variant).map do |variant, units|
        states = {}
        units.group_by(&:state).each { |state, iu| states[state] = iu.count }
        OpenStruct.new(variant: variant, quantity: units.length, states: states)
      end
    end

    def line_items
      if order.complete? and Spree::Config.track_inventory_levels
        order.line_items.select { |li| !li.should_track_inventory? || inventory_units.pluck(:variant_id).include?(li.variant_id) }
      else
        order.line_items
      end
    end

    def finalize!
      InventoryUnit.finalize_units!(inventory_units)
      manifest.each { |item| manifest_unstock(item) }
    end

    def after_cancel
      manifest.each { |item| manifest_restock(item) }
    end

    def after_resume
      manifest.each { |item| manifest_unstock(item) }
    end

    # Updates various aspects of the Shipment while bypassing any callbacks.  Note that this method takes an explicit reference to the
    # Order object.  This is necessary because the association actually has a stale (and unsaved) copy of the Order and so it will not
    # yield the correct results.
    def update!(order)
      old_state = state
      new_state = determine_state(order)
      update_column :state, new_state
      after_ship if new_state == 'shipped' and old_state != 'shipped'
    end

    # Determines the appropriate +state+ according to the following logic:
    #
    # pending    unless order is complete and +order.payment_state+ is +paid+
    # shipped    if already shipped (ie. does not change the state)
    # ready      all other cases
    def determine_state(order)
      return 'canceled' if order.canceled?
      return 'pending' unless order.can_ship?
      return 'pending' if inventory_units.any? &:backordered?
      return 'shipped' if state == 'shipped'
      order.paid? ? 'ready' : 'pending'
    end

    def tracking_url
      @tracking_url ||= shipping_method.build_tracking_url(tracking)
    end

    def include?(variant)
      inventory_units_for(variant).present?
    end

    def inventory_units_for(variant)
      inventory_units.group_by(&:variant_id)[variant.id] || []
    end

    def to_package
      package = Stock::Package.new(stock_location, order)
      inventory_units.includes(:variant).each do |inventory_unit|
        package.add inventory_unit.variant, 1, inventory_unit.state_name
      end
      package
    end

    def set_up_inventory(state, variant, order)
      self.inventory_units.create(variant_id: variant.id, state: state, order_id: order.id)
    end

    private

      def manifest_unstock(item)
        stock_location.unstock item.variant, item.quantity, self
      end

      def manifest_restock(item)
        if item.states["on_hand"].to_i > 0
         stock_location.restock item.variant, item.states["on_hand"], self
        end

        if item.states["backordered"].to_i > 0
          stock_location.restock_backordered item.variant, item.states["backordered"]
        end
      end

      def description_for_shipping_charge
        "#{Spree.t(:shipping)} (#{shipping_method.name})"
      end

      def after_ship
        inventory_units.each &:ship!
        adjustment.finalize!
        send_shipped_email
        touch :shipped_at
      end

      def send_shipped_email
        ShipmentMailer.shipped_email(self.id).deliver
      end

      def ensure_correct_adjustment
        if adjustment
          adjustment.originator = shipping_method
          adjustment.label = shipping_method.adjustment_label
          adjustment.amount = selected_shipping_rate.cost if adjustment.open?
          adjustment.save!
          adjustment.reload
        elsif selected_shipping_rate_id
          shipping_method.create_adjustment shipping_method.adjustment_label, order, self, true, "open"
          reload #ensure adjustment is present on later saves
        end
      end

      def update_order
        order.update!
      end

      def can_get_rates?
        order.ship_address && order.ship_address.valid?
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: keep in mind stackoverflow isn't debugging site.

Comment: I'm trying debug but the code is too deep...

Comment: Can you post the spec that is failing (the one pertaining line 149)?

Comment: Please provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)